# Unable to get local issuer certificate when trying to connect to google fitness API on node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to access the Google fitness API, and I am running my code on a node.js server and I get the following error:

```
> $ node --trace-warnings index.js   (node:14160) Error: unable to get
> local issuer certificate  
>     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)   
>     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)   
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)   
>     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)   
>     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)    (node:14160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejections are depr ecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
> not handled will terminate th e Node.js process with a non-zero exit
> code.   
>     at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:78:15)   
>     at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:95:11)   
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

I tried searching online but couldn't find anything. What is the issue and how do I resolve it?